# Yamldecode with optional value

Tags: terraform

I want to store Route53 entries in a YAML file. However, I'm accounting for records that can also be an alias to let's say an ELB. The code only works if the entries in the YAML file is of one type (`record` or an `alias`, you can't have both in the file). I'm using the following module.

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-route53/blob/master/modules/records/main.tf

```
locals {
  zone_data_raw = yamldecode(file("${path.module}//zone_data.yaml"))
  zone_data = {
      zone_id = local.zone_data_raw.zone_id
      records = [for r in local.zone_data_raw.records : {
        name    = r.name
        type    = r.type
        ttl     = lookup(r, "ttl", null)
        alias   = lookup(r, "alias", {})
        records = lookup(r, "records", null)
      }]
    }
}

module "records" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws//modules/records"
  zone_id = local.zone_data_raw.zone_id
  private_zone = true
  records = local.zone_data.records
}
```

YAML file (Works fine)

```
zone_id: Z12345678
records:
- name: route53-alias1.example.com
  type: A
  alias:
    name: abc.com
    zone_id: Z12345678
- name: route53-alias.example.com
  type: A
  alias:
    name: alias.elb.amazon.com
    zone_id: Z12345678
```

YAML file (Doesn't work)

```
zone_id: Z12345678
records:
- name: route53-alias1.example.com
  type: A
  records:
  - 192.168.0.1
- name: route53-alias.example.com
  type: A
  alias:
    name: alias.elb.amazon.com
    zone_id: Z12345678
```

Error:

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on .terraform/modules/records/modules/records/main.tf line 15, in resource "aws_route53_record" "this":
  15:   for_each = var.create && (var.zone_id != null || var.zone_name != null) ? local.recordsets : tomap({})
    |----------------
    | local.recordsets is object with 2 attributes

The true result value has the wrong type: object is required.
```

UPDATE:

I broke the code and module apart and realized my mistake. In the module, the author turned the records into a map using `tomap`. I was doubling the work but using a for loop to build a map within `locals`. All i had to do was pass in the records from the `yamldecode`.

```
locals {
  workspace_defaults  = file("../_${terraform.workspace}.yaml")
  common_settings = merge(
    yamldecode(local.workspace_defaults)
  )

  zone_data_raw = yamldecode(file("${path.module}//zone_data.yaml"))
}

module "records" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws//modules/records"
  zone_id = local.zone_data_raw.zone_id
  private_zone = true
  records = local.zone_data_raw.records
}
```

Comment: How your `zone_data` relates to the module? How do you use the module?

Comment: Sorry about that, updated with more code

Answer (score 0):

The error happens due to this line `records = lookup(r, "records", null)`. This is because when you mix records and alias, `records` will be once `list` and once `null`.

To overcome the issue, make it empty `list`, not `null`:

```
  zone_data = {
      zone_id = local.zone_data_raw.zone_id
      records = [for r in local.zone_data_raw.records : {
        name    = r.name
        type    = r.type
        ttl     = lookup(r, "ttl", null)
        alias   = lookup(r, "alias", {})
        records = lookup(r, "records", [])
      }]
    }
```

Comment: @sdot257 So what was the issue if my answer did not help?

Comment: it wasn't your code that didn't help it was what I was doing. I have an update at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: @sdot257 Thanks for letting me know. You can answer your own question and accept it. Its better to provide solution as an answer then in the question.